# how i can use gldrawelements for many squares?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am developing a 2D `Open GL` game and i have to draw many squares on screen for a tilemap, with a diferent `glTexCoordPointer` from the texture.

Now, I don't know how to use `Gldrawelements` for draw many squares, which would be the structure of the indices if I want to draw many squares?

And, how can I put each array (vertices), which contains the coordinates of each square on the `vertexbuffer`?

Also, will it be possible to set different `glTexCoordPointer` for each square in just one call to the method or is necessary a loop like with `GlDrawArrays`? But, I want to use `gldrawelements` because i dont want to make a loop which execute many times `gldrawarrays` for each square,  my `fps` drops notably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the squares are adjacent to each other, then use a quad-strip (or a equivalently a triangle-strip):

[image: quad-strip of adjacent quads]

If the squares are disjoint simply use quads

[image]

You can also use a quad-strip (equivalently a triangle-strip) 
in this case by adding degenerate quads (triangles):

```
GLushort indices[] = {A, B, C, D, D, E, E, F, G, H, H, I, I, J, K, L}
```

Two squares with the same vertex positions, but different texture coordinates must be represented with different quads.